# How to let Karma skip a browser if not installed

Tags: testing, karma-jasmine

I have a `karma.config.js` file in a repo that lists different browsers that karma needs to run test on. If I run the test on ubuntu which doesn't have safari install and karma will complain

```
No binary for Safari browser on your platform. Please set "SAFARI_BIN" env variable.
```

How do I configure Karma to automatically skip the browser without giving error if a browser is not installed. I don't want everyone who download the repo to edit the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. After some searching and experimenting. I found a karma plugin that [Karma detect browsers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiO1JDi8frOAhVLlx4KHSEqBVQQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Flitixsoft%2Fkarma-detect-browsers&usg=AFQjCNHC7uFP43cA9UjnW2FlPqQ4x4Qz8w&sig2=W_9p3UFZM-CjaCzsBEKG9Q&cad=rjt). In the karma config, I added

```
detectBrowsers: {
            enable: true,
        },
```

and removed the `browsers` array.
You still have to install the runners for each of the potential browser that you want to test on.
When I run karma now, it will try out different browsers and see if they are installed in the current system. If installed, run the test.

Comment: must this karma-detect-browsers run as a global package ? i installed it locally as a dev dependency.. its failing on my CI server.. but it works locally even though I didn't install it globally. ? did you ?

Comment: I remember I installed locally as a dev dependency. What's your error on CI server?

Comment: the error starts with Error: No provider for "framework:detectBrowsers"! (Resolving: framework:detectBrowsers) ..   never ind.. it's not running yarn install as expected..